# How to open a shell command prompt inside Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using Visual Studio Code, how do I run command-line programs, such as a choco (Chocolatey) command? Do I need to have a separate Command Line (CMD.exe) running outside VS Code, or is there a hotkey/window within Code where I can run those commands?

I see the "Command Palette", but it is not entirely clear what command engines run in that palette.

Comment: BTW, the command palette is Ctrl+Shift+P.

Comment: Looks like version 1.2.0 and above will have an integrated console. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_workbench

Comment: Somewhat related note: I was having trouble opening the native console (`workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole` in Keyboard Shortcuts, `Open New Terminal` in Command Palette), and I found out it was because I needed to first open a folder in vscode. The new console is opened with the current working directory set to the workspace directory in vscode, so I imagine that's why it wouldn't open without choosing a folder first.

Comment: It's actually a lot easier than that. Just go to [Terminal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmQhOnBzg_k) > New Terminal on main navigation bar. On the right hand side, between + and trashcan button, select drop down to choose between Bash, PowerShell, CommandPrompt (cmd.exe), basically it'll automatically display any of the shells you have actually installed on your system.

Comment: try this:  ```ctrl + j``` to show the opened terminal.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

For **integrated terminal** use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

From the release notes:

> With the May release, we are rolling out the initial version of an integrated terminal. You can open the terminal using Ctrl+`, from the View | Toggle Integrated Terminal menu, or from the View > Toggle Integrated Terminal command in the Command Palette.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160616204248/http://code.visualstudio.com/updates/#_workbench (the 1.2.0 May release in 2016)

Comment: On windows UK keyboard back tick did not work for but ctrl and apostrophe worked for me.

Comment: My version at work has an optionon the right click context menu to open the terminal, similar to "Open in Command Prompt", but my version at home doesn't have this option... I shall investigate

Comment: On AZERTY keyboards: 'ctrl + ù'

Answer (score 54):

Use `CMD+Shift+C` or `CTRL+Shift+C` but it will *only* open a **new** outside editor standard bash console.

I hope they will implement an **integrated console**.

Comment: I am not getting that hotkey to work on Windows yet. I will confirm on Mac.

Comment: I tried on another computer and CTRL+Shift+C worked just fine.

Comment: And I agree, I wish it was integrated, but that hotkey works great. Opened right up into the project folder I was using. Thanks again!

Comment: There's an "Open New Command Prompt (Ctrl+Shift+C)" entry in Command Palette but it doesn't do anything at all, not at least on Windows 10.

Comment: Working for me on Windows 7.

Comment: work has started for an integrated terminal console: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/143#issuecomment-213581854

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that worked for me on Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 28):

Can open it with this menu options: `View > Integrated Terminal`

Default keyboard shortcut for **integrated terminal** is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

In vscode you can use multiple integrated terminals.
If you want open another one use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

vscode keys shortcuts are rendered **assuming a standard US keyboard layout**. If you use a different keyboard layout, [please read how](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_keyboard-layouts) can see the representation in your current keyboard.
It's easy, open this menu options: `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`
and on the `Default Keyboard Shortcut` search the command `workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal` then point you mouse to info icon and can see the combination. For me is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ñ</kbd> because I'm using Spanish keyboard layout.

[image]

Also it's cool create an personal shortcuts to toggle into terminals. Open this menu options: `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` and on the `keybinding.json` tab put this:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+pageup",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },{
        "key": "ctrl+pagedown",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    }
]
```

Now when the cursor are focus on terminal, and have more than one terminal, you can navigate through every one with the combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> for previous terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> for next terminal.

**Tip:** If you are focus on the editor, the same keyboard shortcuts can be used to navigate through tabs.

Answer (score 21):

For mac <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> 
For win <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

Answer (score 9):

@brady321's answer is only for US keyboards:

> Note: The following keys are rendered assuming a standard **US keyboard layout**.(https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings)

For instance, UK keyboards use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>:

You can find your shortcut in `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` searching for `workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal`. If you're not using a  US keyboard, it will show you the equivalent shortcut using your keyboard layout:

[image]

To check what the shortcut to open a native console looks like, try to find `workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole` in the shortcuts file.

> More information about integrated terminal at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Answer (score 8):

As MCBL wrote, there is no **integrated console**. You can vote for this feature here: [UserVoice - Integrated terminal](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752357-integrated-terminal) <-- dead link.

#### 3rd party Edit

Uservoice is no longer used and the link above is dead. The feature request for an [integrated terminal might be this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/516314/integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-2019-similar.html).

Comment: There is already a integrated console: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+integrated+terminal Just checkout the correct branch and you can test that feature! See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6654

Answer (score 8):

test with the Ctrl + J keys in ubuntu

Comment: This one works on Fedora 31 (LATAM/US layouts) as well while the ones suggested in the other answers don't.

Answer (score 5):

In the contrary you may also run a terminal inside your visual studio code tool by simply doing the following:

Go to " View > Integrated Terminal " or use the shortcut key " Ctrl + ' "

I believe this is available on later versions of visual studio code. I could do this on version 1.7.0-insider.

Comment: Solve my problems. It's the older version of Visual Studio code that case no action when use the shortcut key " Ctrl + ' ". After update to 1.6, it works.

Answer (score 4):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>`</kbd>**

> Integrated Terminal In Visual Studio Code, you can open an integrated
>   terminal, initially starting at the root of your workspace. This can
>   be very convenient as you don't have to switch windows or alter the
>   state of an existing terminal to perform a quick command line task.
>
> To open the terminal:

- Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>keyboard shortcut with the backtick character.
- Use the View | Toggle Integrated Terminal menu command. From the
  Command
- Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), use the View:Toggle Integrated Terminal
  command.
  [image]
  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: Help > Keyboard Shortcuts Reference  https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I am using **vsCode 1.9.1**.  there are 2 ways as I know

1. You can easily open it by hitting **Ctrl + `** key.
2. Go to **View->Integrated Terminal** like below image

[image: terminal for vscode]

Comment: Menu image is very useful when Ctrl-` is mapped to something else, like, say, [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/). If Ctrl-` is mapped elsewhere, you might also try **Ctrl-Shift-`** which worked for me. But the image is the proverbial lifesaver -- I tend to scan high & low... & here for "*terminal*"... and passed over the danged "*Integrated Terminal*" each time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Test this, This works for me

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ñ</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

On my UK MacBook, when I look in my keyboard shortcuts for VS Code (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts), Toggle Integrated Terminal has the keybinding <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

However, the shortcut works on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>§</kbd>, which is the key on my MacBook that is the same place as the <kbd>`</kbd> on a UK Windows keyboard.

You can take the text editor of the Microsoft, but you can't take the etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` or use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Type to search in keybindings : `workbench.action.terminal.new`.

Double click on Keybinding and add the shortcut you want *(<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is unused in default config).*

Answer (score 0):

Since the Debug Console does not support programs that need to read input from the console, you can enable an external, native console by setting the attribute externalConsole to true in your launch configuration.
lauch.json just write: "externalConsole" : true

Answer (score 0):

I used custom shortcut. Add below keybind to the keybinds.json:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+,",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
    }
]
```

To open keybinds.json

**CTRL + SHIFT + P** then type **Keyboard** and click to **Open Keyboard Shortcuts**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run command line programs is to use the terminal window provided inside VS Code. This way tou will not switch any apps. But to make switching between terminal and other windows I recommend the following :

1. **To open up a terminal** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>
2. **To open up second terminal** - when you are running a node script in the first terminal and it is blocked and you need to run second script at the same time - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>
3. **To focus/switch** back on terminal without reopening :

   1. Press <kbd>F1</kbd> and then type *keyboard shortcuts*
   2. Find *workbench.action.terminal.focus* and set it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> - this slash is usually located right next to your right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. This makes switching between code and terminal very easy because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> are invoked with your right hand and index finger.

Answer (score 0):

### Switch the Integrated Terminal to CMD

1. Open the **Integrated Terminal**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>
2. If a **Bash** terminal is opened while you want a **Command Prompt (cmd)**, simply run the command: `cmd`, in the terminal to switch it to *Command Prompt*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also for MAC its `Ctrl+Shift+`.

I prefer you to change to a custom one.
Open up `Command Palette` by **Command+Shift+P**.

Type '*Keyboard Shortcuts...*' - Select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`

[image].
See **Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal** option there.  Double-tap it to change it to a custom one.

[image]. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
ctrl + shift + `
```

Seems to have done the trick with the default VSCode settings.
If you hover your cursor over the `+`-button to add a new terminal, you can actually see what you need to press for the shortcut.